# Getting 'No auth token for request' warning while uploading a file to Firebase storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

> I am trying to upload an image to cloud Firebase Storage and I have a button to upload the file to the storage. When I click the button the file is uploaded but the console logs a warning.

This is the output while uploading a file:

```
E/StorageUtil( 2806): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest( 2806): no auth token for request
I/zygote  ( 2806): Background concurrent copying GC freed 2141(303KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(124KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 340us total 141.593ms
D/libc-netbsd( 2806): getaddrinfo: get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out( 2806): port:443
I/System.out( 2806): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
E/StorageUtil( 2806): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest( 2806): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 2806): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/flutter ( 2806): Image uploaded
E/StorageUtil( 2806): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest( 2806): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 2806): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out( 2806): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/flutter ( 2806): The user image url => 'uploaded image url'
Application finished.
Exited (sigterm)
```